# Compiling Gearman PHP Library for CentOS 5.8

Tags: centos, centos5, gearman

I've been trying to get Gearman compiled on CentOS 5.8 all afternoon.

Searches have said to install the following via `yum`:

```
yum -y install --enablerepo=remi boost141-devel libgearman-devel e2fsprogs-devel e2fsprogs gcc44 gcc-c++
```

To get the Boost headers working correctly I did this:

```
cp -f /usr/lib/boost141/* /usr/lib/
cp -f /usr/lib64/boost141/* /usr/lib64/
rm -f /usr/include/boost
ln -s /usr/include/boost141/boost /usr/include/boost
```

With all of the dependancies installed and paths setup I then download and compile `gearmand-1.1.2` just fine.

```
wget -O /tmp/gearmand-1.1.2.tar.gz https://launchpad.net/gearmand/1.2/1.1.2/+download/gearmand-1.1.2.tar.gz
cd /tmp && tar zxvf gearmand-1.1.2.tar.gz
./configure && make -j8 && make install
```

That works correctly. So now I need to install the Gearman library for PHP. I have attempted through PECL and downloading the source directly, both result in the same error:

```
checking whether to enable gearman support... yes, shared
not found
configure: error: Please install libgearman
```

What I don't understand is I installed the `libgearman-devel` package which also installed the core `libgearman`. The installation installs `libgearman-devel-0.14-3.el5.x86_64`, `libgearman-devel-0.14-3.el5.i386`, `libgearman-0.14-3.el5.x86_64`, and `libgearman-0.14-3.el5.i386`.

Is it possible the package version is lower than what is required? I'm still poking around with this, but figured I'd throw this up to see if anyone has a solution while I continue to research a fix.

Thanks!

Comment: gearmand is in the EPEL repo for EL5. For that matter, php-pecl-gearman is in remi. Why did you download your own? This is too much trouble for nothing.

Comment: I have a custom compiled PHP version. Installing php-pecl-gearman brings down packaged PHP versions which will conflict with my version already installed. So far the PHP library is the only thing I can't get compiled. And why the `./configure` is not seeing the libgearman is beyond me. libgearman's headers are indeed located at `/usr/include/libgearman`...

Comment: It may also be worth noting that using `./configure --with-gearman=/usr/include/libgearman` also results in the same error.

Comment: OK, so your web app is so old it won't run on PHP 5.3? That sucks. It would probably be easier to fix the web app and use the remi-packaged PHP (5.3.18 as of today).

Comment: Actually, we have PHP 5.4.7 custom compiled with just the bare minimum needed to run our application.

Comment: Ouch. (You know remi-test has PHP 5.4 as well...) Doing this yourself is almost always going to backfire.

Comment: You're looking beyond the actually problem here. Our entire LEMP stack is compiled from source code and runs fine. The real problem here is the library being compiled from source, or running `pecl install gearman` is resulting in the error noted about not being able to see libgearman even though it is in the include path. So please refrain from commenting about the way we installed PHP unless that has something to do with libgearman not being visible; but I highly doubt it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
export GEARMAN_LIB_DIR=/usr/include/libgearman
export GEARMAN_INC_DIR=/usr/include/libgearman
```

That should work, if not you'll have to do some minor edits to config.m4.

Answer (score 2):

Some other helpful notes regarding this can be found here: http://gearman.info/build/centos5-8.html

And based on link above and random googling around this has worked for me without messing lib/include folders:

```
yum install boost141 boost141-devel gcc44 gcc44-c++ uuid-devel
export CC="gcc44"
export CFLAGS="-std=gnu99"
export CXX="gcc44-c++"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/include/boost141"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib64/boost141"
CC=gcc44 CXX=g++44 ./configure
make
make install
```

**UPDATE:** Epel has recently updated to gearmand / libgearman 1.1.8 which is very recent compared to the version they had before (0.14?). So there should be no need to compile it by yourself (except the php pecl extension of course).